Konva JS scroll event propagation super slow when using trackpad
I'm working on a Next JS application that has a PDF rendered by Konva JS. The long term plan is to drag and drop things onto the PDF and save the coordinates. But for now the issue I'm facing is that if I try to scroll on the PDF with my trackpad, the scroll event that's fired takes like 2-3 seconds to fully resolve. I'm not sure why. When I use the sidebar to scroll, it works fine. So I'm pretty sure it's the event propagation that's the issue here.
My code is in this GitHub repo: https://github.com/ankit8697/PDF-Autofill
You can find the PDF component under src/components/PDFShape.tsx
Thanks for your help!
